# convert executable to node module/object

Tags: javascript, node.js, cmd, automation, node-modules

I tried searching, but with not luck.

I want to convert/wrap an executable to use it easily and nicely in node, and not calling child_process.exec all the time.
For example, if I wanted to do it with git, instead of `git help` or `git clone git://repo.git` I'll have somethings like:
`var git = new cmd('git');
git.help();
git.clone('git://repo.git');
etc..`

Doe's anyone knows if something like that exist?

The closest thing I've found so far is [run-cmd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-cmd) which can do somethings like that but not automatically. I'll need to create the object with all the parameters I want.

Thanks,
Ariel

Comment: Well, there's [js-git](https://github.com/creationix/js-git)

Comment: thanks, I know. I gave git as an example. I ment if I'll want to do it with another thing that doesn't have a node library, let's say run the browser with command line options or anything else that doesn't have a solution for node. I'm looking for a general library

Comment: Why not build one yourself? It shouldn't be a lot of work. You could see what grunt-shell is doing and pick it up from there

Comment: I guess that's what I'll do :) I wanted to know if there's something I didn't heard about or haven't found on the internet before I start writing something

Comment: Good luck with that!